# Fortify Scan Append option using maven plugin

Tags: fortify

How can i append fpr report using maven plugin? Is it possible to do scan -append using maven fortify commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this directly with the maven plugin. *Merging* and *-append* are different bits of functionality.

You could however use this by just performing the translation stage with maven, such as:

```
$sourceanalyzer -b my_maven_test -clean
$sourceanalyzer -b my_maven_test mvn sca:translate
$sourceanalyzer -b my_maven_test -scan -f results.fpr -append
```

Unfortunately this is the only way to currently get this functionality. However there are subsequent issues with appending (such as the code should be completely logically independent to be scanned separately ..which can be surprisingly difficult to determine) and can be harder to maintain the scanning process going forward. I would generally advise to try and scan the entire project in one go if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried a similar way and it worked out. I had built different modules with same build id and did a single scan and i was able to successfully generate a single fpr report for multiple builds.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you can call a .jar file (which I believe is possible in Maven).  Look at the SCA Utilities user guide.  You are looking for the Merge functionality.  After the Fortify Maven plugin, you should be able to make another build step that then does the merge.  If you want a report after that, you can also make a build step that executes the report generator.

Answer (score 0):

"-append" is a feature that should add results into an existing FPR. There is no valid reason to do this, unless your scan is too large to run in one pass and you have no other option.  For the past few years, performance options have improved to the point that you should never have to use "-append" anymore.  Please see Technical Support for the latest shortcomings of this command, if you are convinced you must use it.